# How can I install Uplay on ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, wine

As stated in title, how can I do it? When I start Uplay it gives me an error and it's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't yet , there are still alot of bugs needed to be fixed
Check out this link for more information 
http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-bugs/2012-May/322485.html

If you really need to use this on Ubuntu , there is still one way , Install Windows 8 ( Free Version ) in Virtualbox and through that , you play the games.

you can also check out another game client that runs nativly on Linux

DESURA
http://www.desura.com/

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can install Uplay in Wine and play Windows games. For me the simplest way was to install Lutris. See https://lutris.net/

There is a script which helps you install Uplay https://lutris.net/games/uplay/

Also Lutris helps you istall Steam in Wine to play Steam games for Windows

Answer (score 0):

My experience on Ubuntu 20.20 is that for Steam, you don't need Wine or anything, it'll install all the necessary things on its own. As for Uplay, I managed to get it working with Wine-staging and Lutris with the help of this guide: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-get-gog-galaxy-on-linux-4689192 (I didn't need GOG so I summarized the whole process here: https://edison23.net/blog/uplay-on-ubuntu/ ; not much new there compared to the original guide, just less explanations of what Lutris and Wine are).